# random values with mysql

Tags: mysql, random, mysql-workbench

I want to create different random values for each line in a table, i tried the following:

```
select t.col1, rnd() from t;
```

but `rnd()` just created 1 random value equal for every line.  is it possible create n different values for n rows just with mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with [`rand()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). It creates a new random number for every row in the table

```
select col1, rand()
from t
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee6f9/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

It should create a new number for each line. Documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Is it cast as an int or something? Also if you don't want a number from 0 to 1 then you'll need to do something like this instead:

```
select t.col1, FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5)) from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rnd()` function is short for 'round,' it was simply rounding, in this case, nothing.